# How to set the current working directory?

Tags: python, working-directory

How to set the current working directory in Python?

Answer (score 1015, accepted):

Try [`os.chdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir)

> ```
> import os
> os.chdir(path)
> ```
>
> Change the current working directory to path. Availability: Unix, Windows.

Comment: Can you give me an example of format of the path? I am using os x; when I am trying to set a path I am getting an error - >>> import os
>>> os.chdir(Users/Me/Desktop/M/PTS/Python/t1.py)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    os.chdir(/Users/Me/Desktop/M/PTS/Python/t1.py)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: @Pooja25 The path must be a string. in addition, chdir expects a directory name, but you are specifying a file.

Comment: I usually use `os.getcwd()` first, and that shows me the format of the accepted input for `os.chdir()`.

Answer (score 153):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
import os
os.chdir(default_path)
```

Answer (score 70):

```
import os
print os.getcwd()  # Prints the current working directory
```

To set the working directory:

```
os.chdir('c:\\Users\\uname\\desktop\\python')  # Provide the new path here
```

Comment: –1: This answer is not useful — *because it was already posted six years ago.*

Comment: @cpb2 Semicolons at the end of a statement are not a syntax error in Python. You can even use them to put multiple statements on one line D-: But they are certainly very bad style.

Comment: The `\u` in the string on the other hand *is* a syntax error; that should be `\\u`.

Comment: @jwodder - I agree with you. OTOH, there are at least 24 people for which this was useful. Perhaps it was the fact that he covered ítems in the comments of the accepted answer: 1) format of explicit paths, 2) how to get examples of such (with `getcwd`).... remarkable.

Comment: You need double slashes for each directory level when dealing with Windows.

Comment: @SDsolar or you can use a raw string: `os.chdir(r'c:\Users\uname\desktop\python')`

Answer (score 15):

It work for **Mac** also

```
import os
path="/Users/HOME/Desktop/Addl Work/TimeSeries-Done"
os.chdir(path)
```

To check working directory

```
os.getcwd()
```

Comment: `Python` one of the core ideas of python is to work cross-plattform.

Comment: Thanks for this example, I was trying (the usual) ``"~/etc"`` without success.

Comment: @PatrickT if you want to expand `~`, you need to use `os.path.expanduser("~/etc")`, which will then expand to the full path (`/path/to/homedir/etc`)