# How to change C drive to F drive using python Script

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set the current working directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810743/how-to-set-the-current-working-directory-in-python)

How to change `C:\>` to `F:\>` using Python

I tried

```
import os
os.chdir("F:")
```

but got an error.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810743/how-to-set-the-current-working-directory-in-python

Comment: I tried with this code giving error import os
os.chdir("F:")

Comment: What error? `os.chdir("F:")` worked fine for me

Comment: And what is the error you received?  Error messages tend to contain useful clues about what went wrong, they should not be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You need the extra backslash:

```
import os  
os.chdir("F:\\")
```