# InnoSetup messes up Python script?

Tags: python, inno-setup

I have a Python script that reads an excel spreadsheet. It does so only if the spreadsheet is in the same folder as the script.

Now, when I use py2exe to convert the script to `.exe` and then copy my `.xls` file to the `dist` folder it creates and where the `.exe` file is, it runs fine. But, when I use InnoSetup to make an installer, and then I copy my `.xls` file to the program files folder where the main executable is, the program doesn't find my `.xls` file anymore, even though the `.exe` and `.xls` are in the same folder.

What might be the problem?

Comment: InnoSetup doesn't hurt your files. Look for solution related to your application (this is for 99.9% not InnoSetup related). Optionally post your InnoSetup script and describe, which file you need, and where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not really related with Inno Setup.

My guess is:

- you're creating a shortcut icon for your exe program in the installer,
- your program doesn't really open the excel file located in the exe directory, but in the [*working directory*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810743/how-to-set-the-current-working-directory-in-python) of the application.
- the Icon entry is specifying the wrong `WorkingDir` parameter.

To *fix* your installer, change your [icon] entry, specify the correct `WorkingDir` or leave it blank and, according to the [documentation](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_iconssection.htm), the installer will try to use the path of the `Filename` parameter, for example:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MYPROG.EXE"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
```

Comment: @geekkid, you're very welcome, and upvotes are welcome too. X-D

Comment: A better fix is to make your program *actually* look in its own folder, instead of using the working dir.  Then you wouldn't have had this problem in the first place.

Comment: @miral IMHO before thinking on any _fix_, the better is the developer understand the difference between the exe folder and the working dir, which happens to be the same lot of times, but not always. There's some programs that works OK with opening the files in the exe folder while others works OK with opening the files in the working directory, which IMHO is a better approach.

Comment: When trying to locate specific known pre-named resource files, typically no application should ever be ambiguous about where they are -- it should know exactly where they are because it knows exactly where they were installed.  (Using the working folder for this is ambiguous because that is outside of the application's control.)  The only real exception to this is for command-line applications where the working folder is used as the base folder for relative paths entered by the user -- but even there they should be internally converted to absolute paths as soon as possible.

Comment: Note that "knowing where they are" doesn't always mean the app folder -- sometimes they could be in the user's data folders, or by using some other setting to look up a "data directory" etc.  There are some apps that use the working dir as a sort of informal profile folder to let one app run with different configs when run by different shortcuts, but this is just lazy design.  (Which isn't necessarily bad -- I've done that myself in some bespoke situations where I know it can't be abused.  The key is to *know* that it's lazy and where its limitations lie.)