# How to open up an Image in Python

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am new to Stackoverflow and still learning python but I am attempting to begin a project of mine.
I plan on creating a filter for images using python. The first step I would like to learn is how to open up an image in python. This is what I have so far:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('Jordan.jpg')
im.show()
```

Am I on the right track? Iam using Python 2.7

Comment: When you run the code what happens?  any error?

Comment: Didn't this work?  I think any tutorial on PIL will tell you how to open an image.  I'd also recommend checking out scikit-image if PIL doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: use [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) instead of PIL. PIL is  deprecated.

Comment: @SSC I get an error  saying "Windows Photo Viewer cant open this picture because either the picture is deleted or its in a location that isnt available". I have the photo inside the same folder as in the .py file

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you've got the filename correct and the .jpg is in the working directory? Maybe give to full path of the jpg just to make sure that's not the problem...

Comment: @hft how can I make sure the .jpg is in the working directory?

Comment: Are you invoking your script from its own directory or some other?

Comment: @JosephM for setting the working directory check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810743/how-to-set-the-current-working-directory-in-python

Comment: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html

Comment: Try with the full path to the image to rule out if the path is wrong. Alternately try to open the image as a file and see if that works.

Comment: Hello Joseph, welcome to Stack Overflow.  In its current state, I think your question is too broad for the SO format.  Please share the errors you've encountered or the specific question you have so that we can help you better.

Comment: @JosephM, you can print the value of os.getcwd() to check what directory you are in. To do this you need to import the os module first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most natural python object that corresponds to an image is a multi-dimensional array; that's the most natural representation and it's also the best data structure to manipulate an image, as you intend to do by creating a filter.

Python has an array module, however, for creating and manipulating multi-dimensional arrays (eg, creating a filter), i highly recommend installing two python libraries [NumPy](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html) and [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html) either from the links supplied here or *pip* installing them:

```
pip install numpy
pip install scipy


>>> from scipy import misc as MSC
>>> imfile = "~/path/to/an/image.jpg"
```

use the ***imread*** function in scipy's miscellaneous module, which in fact just calls PIL under the hood; this function will read in jpeg as well as png images

```
>>> img = MSC.imread(imfile)
```

verify that it is a NumPy array

```
>>> isinstance(img, NP.ndarray)
True
```

a color image has three axes: X (width) Y (height), and Z (the three elements that comprise an RGB tuple;

first two axes are the pixel width and height of the image,
the last dimension should be '3' (or '4' for an 'png' image which has an alpha channel)

```
>>> img.shape
(200, 200, 3)
```

selecting one pixel roughly from the image center (a single RGB 3-tuple)

```
>>> img[100,100,:]
array([83, 26, 17], dtype=uint8)
```

if you call Matplotlib's *imshow* method and pass in this NumPy array, it will render the image