# How to choose where numpy.savez saves the files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I use `numpy.savez` to register my arrays as .npz files ( and it works very well).

But it saves the files in the folder where there is the script.
Technically, my program is a while loop which will save 100 files one at a time.

I would like to be able to select at the beginning of the process ( or write full adress) a place on my computer  ,where to save, and then for each iteration have numpy.savez to save them where I indicated.

Because I would not want either to say 100 times " I want you to save it there".

I looked at the scipy docs but I did not find any solutions.

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: Er.. shouldn't **you** pass a path to the directory you want to save the files no?

Comment: I understand the words you use but not the meaning ! ahah Sorry my "noobish" approach of it.

What you say seems to be what I am looking for, but what seems obvious to you is not to me ^^ Can you elaborate ?

Comment: [Read the docs!](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) The first parameter is a file or filename.

Comment: Right now I use the first parameter to define my file name. 
You say to manage where it will save, I should write the full adress of the location I want it to go ?

Comment: Yes, precisely. If you just give the name of the file, rather than the full path, it will go into the current working directory (although note [you *can* change the cwd](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1810743/3001761)).

Comment: I do not understand :  open file (file-like object)  actually

Comment: That's so if you've *already* opened a file (`with open(filename) as f_:`) you can pass the open file object (`f_`) rather than the name/path (`filename`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the path the the folder that you want to save them in as a variable, then combine that path with the filename of each with [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

```
import os
import numpy as np

BASE_PATH = "/path/to/base"

for i in xrange(100):
    x = np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, 100) #make the array to save
    file_name = "{0}.npz".format(i)
    np.savez( os.path.join(BASE_PATH, file_name), x )
```