# Making Python run a few lines before my script

Tags: python, python-import

I need to run a script `foo.py`, but I need to also insert some debugging lines to run before the code in `foo.py`. Currently I just put those lines in `foo.py` and I'm careful not to commit that to Git, but I don't like this solution.

What I want is a separate file `bar.py` that I don't commit to Git. Then I want to run:

```
python /somewhere/bar.py /somewhere_else/foo.py
```

What I want this to do is first run some lines of code in `bar.py`, and then run `foo.py` as `__main__`. It should be in the same process that the `bar.py` lines ran in, otherwise the debugging lines won't help.

Is there a way to make `bar.py` do this?

Someone suggested this:

```
import imp
import sys

# Debugging code here

fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(sys.argv[1])
imp.load_module('__main__', fp, pathname, description)
```

The problem with that is that because it uses import machinery, I need to be on the same folder as `foo.py` to run that. I don't want that. I want to simply put in the full path to `foo.py`.

Also: The solution needs to work with `.pyc` files as well.

Comment: Can you make an alias and pipe it into your actual call? E.g. alias `pytester=python -m bar.py`, then call `pytester | python foo.py`. You would need to get foo.py to accept data on sys.stdin. *Edit:* Or even skip the alias altogether and just call `python /path/to/bar.py | python /path/to/foo.py`.

Comment: Can't you simply chdir to the path of foo before importing it?

Comment: @GerardvanHelden Not a clean solution. I can think of a few practical problems that would cause, since the script expects to be in a specific folder.

Comment: If this is all for debugging just debug with this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke Sorry I'm already invested in the debugger I use and I have no interest in switching to a different one.

Comment: @AndyKubiak Passing data as stdin into `foo.py` doesn't help me. I need to run actual Python lines of code there. I don't see how I could do that with your suggestion.

Comment: @RamRachum some things are better than others, you shouldn't be afraid of change. But your call.

Comment: @RamRachum maybe just create a function that will copy the file with debugging lines added. Messy as it is but it's guaranteed to work. `for line in fileLines: if line in linesToDebug: newFile.write(debuggingLine)` sort of a thing.

Comment: @RamRachum  Maybe just add the debugging stuff at the beginning/end of the line followed/preceded by a `;`, the line numbers will still match.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke If I ever find myself needing to break out of jail using only a napkin and a bobpin, I will definitely contact you for advice :) Unfortunately your new hack won't work because I have some function definitions, which can't fit on one line.

Comment: @RamRachum :) thank you, I'd be delighted. By the way, maybe `lambda` will work? :D

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke Nah, you can't put a 30-line function in a lambda.

Comment: @RamRachum actually, there is a way to fit all your stuff in one line: `a = 'def hack():\n    print("this is a hell of a hack")\nhack()'; exec(a)`

Comment: can you do `cat bar.py foo.py | python`

Comment: @EliKorvigo Might work but too hacky for me.

Comment: @NicE I think this won't work because the code might run different as stdin, but I'll give it a try later.

Comment: will you accept shell script?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Reluctantly :) If there isn't a Python-only solution, and your shell script solution isn't too bad, then yes.

Comment: i will guarantee you it's ugly. it will just concat two pieces and run a temporary file.

Comment: Would you be willing/able to add a sitecustomize or usercustomize file?

Comment: @JeremyAllen I'm not sure how these work, so I'll be happy to hear.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Python has a mechanism for running code at startup; the [site](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) module.

```
"This module is automatically imported during initialization."
```

The site module will attempt to import a module named `sitecustomize` before `__main__` is imported. 
It will also attempt to import a module named `usercustomize` if your environment instructs it to.

For example, you could put a sitecustomize.py file in your site-packages folder that contains this:

```
import imp

import os

if 'MY_STARTUP_FILE' in os.environ:
    try:
        file_path = os.environ['MY_STARTUP_FILE']
        folder, file_name = os.path.split(file_path)
        module_name, _ = os.path.splitext(file_name)
        fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(module_name, [folder])
    except Exception as e:
        # Broad exception handling since sitecustomize exceptions are ignored
        print "There was a problem finding startup file", file_path
        print repr(e)
        exit()

    try:
        imp.load_module(module_name, fp, pathname, description)
    except Exception as e:
        print "There was a problem loading startup file: ", file_path
        print repr(e)
        exit()
    finally:
        # "the caller is responsible for closing the file argument" from imp docs
        if fp:
            fp.close()
```

Then you could run your script like this:

```
MY_STARTUP_FILE=/somewhere/bar.py python /somewhere_else/foo.py
```

- You could run any script before foo.py without needing to add code to reimport `__main__`.
- Run `export MY_STARTUP_FILE=/somewhere/bar.py` and not need to reference it every time

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`execfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) if the file is `.py` and [uncompyle2](https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2/blob/master/scripts/uncompyle2) if the file is `.pyc`.

Let's say you have your file structure like:

```
test|-- foo.py
    |-- bar
         |--bar.py
```

**foo.py**

```
import sys

a = 1
print ('debugging...')

# run the other file
if sys.argv[1].endswith('.py'): # if .py run right away
    execfile(sys.argv[1], globals(), locals())
elif sys.argv[1].endswith('.pyc'): # if .pyc, first uncompyle, then run
    import uncompyle2
    from StringIO import StringIO
    f = StringIO()
    uncompyle2.uncompyle_file(sys.argv[1], f)
    f.seek(0)
    exec(f.read(), globals(), locals())
```

**bar.py**

```
print a
print 'real job'
```

And in `test/`, if you do:

```
$ python foo.py bar/bar.py
$ python foo.py bar/bar.pyc
```

Both, outputs the same:

```
debugging...
1
real job
```

Please also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32261548/547820).

Comment: This would have been my ideal solution, but unfortunately `execfile` doesn't work for `.pyc` files, and I need that.

Comment: @RamRachum, I updated the answer for `.pyc` files. It solves the problem if your concern is not the time but you actually do not have the `.py` file.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have something along the lines of:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # some code
```

Instead, write your code in a function `main()` in `foo` and then do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then, in bar, you can import foo and call `foo.main()`.

Additionaly, if you need to [change the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810743/how-to-set-the-current-working-directory-in-python), you can use the `os.chdir(path)` method, e.g. `os.chdir('path/of/bar')` .

Comment: Sorry, that's too big of a change for `foo.py`. It's a big code file that dozens of people use in my company and I can't refactor it. Also, there might be other differences that we're not thinking of when launching the file like that and I don't want to take chances.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

bar.py

```
imp.load_source('__main__', '../../foo.py')
```

for me it runs whatever is in foo.py (before and inside **main**)

After, maybe what you do in bar.py might be more tricky that my basic test.

The good thing with load_source is that it imports the .pyc if it already exists or initiates a "compile" of the .py and then imports the .pyc.

Answer (score 1):

`bar.py` would have to behave like the Python interpreter itself and run `foo.py` (or `foo.pyc`, as you asked for that) as if it was the main script. This is surprisingly hard. My 90% solution to do that looks like so:

```py
def run_script_as_main(cmdline):
    # It is crucial to import locally what we need as we
    # later remove everything from __main__
    import sys, imp, traceback, os
    # Patch sys.argv
    sys.argv = cmdline
    # Clear the __main__ namespace and set it up to run
    # the secondary program
    maindict = sys.modules["__main__"].__dict__
    builtins = maindict['__builtins__']
    maindict.clear()
    maindict['__file__'] = cmdline[0]
    maindict['__builtins__'] = builtins
    maindict['__name__'] = "__main__"
    maindict['__doc__'] = None
    # Python prepends a script's location to sys.path
    sys.path[0] = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(cmdline[0]))
    # Treat everything as a Python source file, except it
    # ends in '.pyc'
    loader = imp.load_source
    if maindict["__file__"].endswith(".pyc"):
        loader = imp.load_compiled
    with open(cmdline[0], 'rb') as f:
        try:
            loader('__main__', maindict["__file__"], f)
        except Exception:
            # In case of an exception, remove this script from the
            # stack trace; if you don't care seeing some bar.py in
            # traceback, you can leave that out.
            ex_type, ex_value, ex_traceback = sys.exc_info()
            tb = traceback.extract_tb(ex_traceback, None)[1:]
            sys.stderr.write("Traceback (most recent call last):\n")
            for line in traceback.format_list(tb):
                sys.stderr.write(line)
            for line in traceback.format_exception_only(ex_type, ex_value):
                sys.stderr.write(line)
```

This mimics the default behavior of the Python interpreter
relatively closely. It sets system globals `__name__`, `__file__`,
`sys.argv`, inserts the script location into `sys.path`, clears the global namespace etc.

You would copy that code to `bar.py` or import it from somewhere and use it like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # You debugging setup goes here
    ...
    # Run the Python program given as argv[1]
    run_script_as_main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Then, given this:

```
$ find so-foo-bar
so-foo-bar
so-foo-bar/debugaid
so-foo-bar/debugaid/bar.py
so-foo-bar/foo.py
```

and `foo.py` looking like this:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "My name is", __name__
    print "My file is", __file__
    print "My command line is", sys.argv
    print "First 2 path items", sys.path[:2]
    print "Globals", globals().keys()
    raise Exception("foo")
```

... running `foo.py` via `bar.py` gives you that:

```
    $ python so-foo-bar/debugaid/bar.py so-foo-bar/foo.py
    My name is __main__
    My file is so-foo-bar/foo.py
    My command line is ['so-foo-bar/foo.py']
    First 2 path items ['~/so-foo-bar', '/usr/local/...']
    Globals ['__builtins__', '__name__', '__file__', 'sys', '__package__', '__doc__']
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "so-foo-bar/foo.py", line 9, in 
        raise Exception("foo")
    Exception: foo
```

While I'd guess that `run_script_as_main` is lacking in some interesting details, it's pretty close to the way Python would run `foo.py`.

Answer (score 0):

The `foo.py` need not be on the same folder as the main folder. Use

```
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/dirWithFoo/:$PYTHONPATH
```

To add the path that `foo` resides to Python path. Now you can

```
from foo import myfunc

myfunc()
```

And make myfunc do whatever u want

Answer (score 0):

This solution is what ended up working well for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import imp
import sys
import os.path

file_path = sys.argv.pop(1)
assert os.path.exists(file_path)

folder, file_name = os.path.split(file_path)

###############################################################################
#                                                                             #

# Debugging cruft here

#                                                                             #
###############################################################################


module_name, _ = os.path.splitext(file_name)
sys.path.append(folder)
imp.load_module('__main__', *imp.find_module(module_name))
```

Comment: You'll find a more general version of that approach in my answer, which goes to some length to avoid unwanted side-effects for the script that is run.