# How to execute compiled python code

Tags: python, pyc

I have a compiled Python file, `path/program.pyc`.

I want to execute it with my current `globals()` and `locals()`. I tried:

```
with open('path/program.pyc','rb') as f:
   code = f.read()
   exec(code, globals(), locals())
```

More specifically, what I want to have is:

**a.py**:

```
a = 1
# somehow run b.pyc
```

**b.py**:

```
print(a)
```

When I run `a.py`, I want to see the output: `1`.

Actually [`execfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) does exactly what I want, but it only works for `.py` files not `.pyc` files. I am looking for a version of `execfile()` that works for `.pyc` files.

Comment: You want to run the code from b in a?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, but I only have `b.pyc` not `b.py`.

Comment: A simple way would be to uncompyle the pyc, for small files that would involve very little overhead. https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I see. Thanks. However, isn't it upsetting you too that not being able to use the `.pyc` right away without bothering to uncompyle? Python should have been making things easier, not harder. Right?

Comment: I guess it is down to the fact that it is much easier go from source to bytecode than to  bytecode to source although that is not to say that it cannot be done, I just thought of uncompyle when I saw the question, I have used it quite a few times and it worked well always.

Comment: If you do want to go down the uncompyle route, http://pastebin.com/209wP33v

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Can you post your answer as a normal answer instead of comment so that I can upvote/accept it.

Comment: sure done, you might be a better answer so no hurry in accepting

Comment: The variable `a` is undefined in module `b` so how would you expect that to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a better way but using [uncompyle2](https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2/blob/master/scripts/uncompyle2) to get the source and execing will do what you need:

```
a = 1

import uncompyle2
from StringIO import StringIO
f = StringIO()
uncompyle2.uncompyle_file('path/program.pyc', f)
f.seek(0)
exec(f.read(), globals(), locals())
```

Running  `b.pyc` from `a` should output `1`.

Answer (score -3):

Use [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)

Note that you need to use standard python package notation rather than a path and you will need to make sure your file is on `sys.path`

Something like `__import__('path.program', globals(), locals())` should do the trick.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but I couldn't make it work. I updated my question with the details.

Comment: When you import a python package you don't put '.py' on the end.  Look at my example again, there is no '.pyc'

Comment: Did you read what I said?  Leave it out completely. 
`__import__('b', globals(), locals())`

Comment: Same error. Can you please put an example in your answer?