# Use .py or .pyc file when sharing/backing up?

Tags: python, pyc

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/if-python-is-interpreted-what-are-pyc-files) tells me that a .pyc file gets created when a .py file is run, which I understand saves loading time when re-run. Which makes me wonder what the point of the .py file is after the .pyc is created.

When backing up my code, or sharing it, I don't want to include redundant or extraneous files. Which filetype should I focus on?

Side question: I have one script that calls another. After running them, the called script got a .pyc file written, but the master script that does the calling did not. Why would that be?

Comment: If you ever wish to edit or debug your code, you need the `.py`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878479/why-are-main-runnable-python-scripts-not-compiled-to-pyc-files-like-modules for your second question.

Comment: So `.py` is the 'master' file, essentially, and `.pyc` can always be regenerated from it?

Comment: `.pyc` is the compiled file (from `.py` which contains the source code), it contains the byte code

Comment: Some of my thought. Backing up code should use .py, sharing could be both, use .pyc if you you want to add some difficulty for others to access the source code, though there is still way to get back .py from .pyc.

Comment: the .py file contains the source code that could be useful to add updates.

Comment: ``.pyc`` files are specific to the version of Python that created them.  Anyone with a different Python version would not be able to use them, even if the original ``.py`` is compatible with that version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to run your Python script, all you *really* need is `.pyc` which is the bytecode generated from your source code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259786/how-to-execute-compiled-python-code) for details on running a `.pyc` file. I will warn that some of the detials are bit twisty.

However I recommend including your source code and leaving out your `.pyc` files as they are generated automatically by the Python Interpreter. Besides, if you, or another person would want to revise/revisit your source code at a later point, you would need the `.py` files. Furthermore, it is usually best practice to just include your source code.

Answer (score 5):

Python .pyc files are generated when a module is imported, not when a top level script is run. I'm not sure what you mean by calling, but if you ran your master script from the command line and it imported the other script, then only the imported one gets a .pyc.

As for distributing .pyc files, they are minor version sensitive. If you bundle your own python or distribute multiple python-version sensitive files, then maybe. But best practice is to distribute the .py files.

Python's script and module rules seem a bit odd until you consider its installation model. A common installation model is that executables are installed somewhere on the system's `PATH` and shared libraries are installed somewhere in a library path.

Python's `setup.py` does the same thing. Top level scripts go on the PATH but modules and packages go in an library path. For instance on my system, `pdb3` (a top level script) is at `/usr/bin/pdb3` and `os` (an imported module) is at `/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py`. Suppose python compiled `pdb3` to `pdb3.pyc`. Well, I'd still call `pdb3` and the .pyc is useless. So why clutter the path?

Its common for installs to run as root or administrator so you have write access on those paths. But you wouldn't have write access to them later as a regular user. You can have `setup.py` generate .pyc files during install. You get the right .pyc files for whatever python you happen to have, and since you are running as root/admin during install you still have acess to the directories. Trying to build .pyc files later is a problem because a regular user doesn't have access to the directories.

So, best practice is to distribute .py files and have setup.py build the .pyc during install.

Comment: By 'call' I mean it opens and runs another script. Am I not using the right term?

Specifically, in my master script I have a couple lines that import an external module that's housed in another `.py` file, and then run the `main()` function of that module.

Comment: @joechoj - Its ambiguous. You can `import` a module and call its functions (you get a .pyc) or you can execute a script as a child process using something like `subprocess` (no .pyc) but you can't call a script. When you say "it runs another script" that implies that its being executed as an independent subprocess but I'm not sure that's what you mean here. Long story short, if you used the `import` keyword, you imported it and you get a .pyc.

Comment: @joechoj - I am sounding pedantic here and normally looser language is fine. In this case, where we are figuring out when .pyc files get created, it does make a difference.