# Extending system path like PyCharm, outside of it

Tags: python, pycharm

So I created a module in PyCharm and it works great within PyCharm since PyCharm fixes the system path by running this code by itself:

```
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend('D:\\Users\\rk\\projects\\GGM\\Code')
```

This means that I cannot run that module from a terminal since I am not extend the sys path in each and every script in that module. Is there a way to extend the system path like PyCharm for each and every script in that module in an automated way without having to do a bunch of sys.path.extend in every file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646

Comment: @cricket_007, I do not want to modify the PYTHONPATH manually and hence the question to see if it is possible.

Comment: AFAIK, that's the only way to do it without writing it in every module needing a different path

Comment: thanks @cricket_007, perhaps there is a way to invoke sys.path.extend like PyCharm before any file in that module is run?

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32258020/2308683

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: I want the solution to work on both

Comment: as well as `PYTHONPATH` you can run `pip install -e .` in your modules' folders, afaik this creates a simlink and avoids having to set environment variables manually