# How to change the default working directory in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, working-directory

I have a quick question about the default working directly on python. 
I am currently using the python 2.7. In this case the default working directly is the `C:/Python27`. 
I want to change this permanently to another directory. 
Even if we write down following on shell, the default working directory will go back to the original `C:/Python27` automatically.

```
import os

os.chdir('a path')
```

Does any one know how to set up default directory permanently to "the path" which keeps the directory after the closing the shell? 
This is a different question from how to change working directory just by the function temporarily.
Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: How are you launching your script?

Comment: You mean when you double-click `python.exe` or write `python` in the console?

Comment: When you start Python, a new environment is created - so when you change the current working directory, it is effectively changed in this environment ; however when closing Python the original environment is restored. You can't do what you want in Windows there is no bash `source` equivalent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the current working directory in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810743/how-to-set-the-current-working-directory-in-python)

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith It is different question totally. I used os.chdir but it still goes back to the default working directory after closing and relaunch program. Did you put -1?

Answer (score 4):

The working directory of the `python` directory is the directory from which it was started. If from a console (`cmd.exe`) I do `cd /some/dir` and then start python, its working directory will be `/some/dir`.

If you want an interactive console started at a given directory you have some options:

- Using a shortcut, you can change its `Start in` field, in the properties tab, to point to your target directory.
- Use `IPython` instead, and add a [startup script](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/overview.html#startup-files) to the default profile so it always start at the target directory. IPython is an enhanced interactive with lots of useful features.

If you are running from a script and want to switch to the folder where you script is stored, you could use `os.cd(os.path.dirname(__file__))`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!
i decided to use IDE pycharm then i can keep working on a directory on where i want to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching Python from the start menu of Windows, right click on the icon and select more -> file location.

Once there you can right click on the shortcut and select properties. From there you should be able to define the 'Start in:' location.