# How to move to specific directory in python GUI?

Tags: python

this is a python related question
I would like to insert a line of code so that when the code is run on python, it always starts at at specific directory.
I know you can move to parent directory or to a directory in the current path, but is their a way to move to a specific directory regardless of my current directory?

Comment: Look at `os.chdir()` and use an absolute path (e.g. start with `/` for unix or `<drive_letter>:` for windows)

Comment: you can use `os.chdir(path)` this .

Comment: What [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810743/how-to-set-the-current-working-directory-in-python) way? (Try search first!)

Comment: Thanks the magic was in entering the absolute path rather than something like (/Tensorflow)