# Python mysql error with cursor

Tags: python, mysql

Hi I get an error when I try to connect to a mysql database.

```
import threading
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config

class Queue (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, lock):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.lock = lock
    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                dbconfig = read_db_config()
                conn = MySQLConnection(**dbconfig)
                cursor = conn.cursor()
            except Error as e:
                print(e)
            finally:
                cursor.close()
                conn.close()
```

This is a striped part of the code but I still get the same error on the line after `finally:` it says that `cursor` is not defined.
The code is running in a Deamon on Ubuntu.

EDIT:
Some more information about the code
`read_db_config()`

```
from configparser import ConfigParser


def read_db_config(filename='config.ini', section='mysql'):
    """ Read database configuration file and return a dictionary object
    :param filename: name of the configuration file
    :param section: section of database configuration
    :return: a dictionary of database parameters
    """
    # create parser and read ini configuration file
    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read(filename)

    # get section, default to mysql
    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        items = parser.items(section)
        for item in items:
            db[item[0]] = item[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('{0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))

    return db
```

And the config file with false values

```
[mysql]
host = IP
database = database
user = user
password = password
```

EDIT2:
Running the code without the try statement gave this error

```
mysql not found in the config.ini file
```

Can it be that my read_db_config() function can't find the config file but they are in the same folder.

Comment: If you're getting an exception before the `cursor = conn.cursor()` line, then the cursor.close() will likely fail ...

Comment: Okej so must likely the `conn = MySQLConnection(**dbconfig)` is wrong.

Comment: I got a new error after deleting the try statement. `mysql not found in the config.ini file`

Comment: Found the error know I was calling the python script when I'am outside the folder. But is there a way to avoid this error so I can call the python script outside the folder?

Comment: Try `os.chdir` -- http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So ... after a bit of troubleshooting ...

The solution was to [set the current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810760/3259125) when calling the script from outside the folder in which the config file was located.

Comment: Yes it's often the simplest things that is hardest to find.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran your code from read_db_config and everything it`s okay.
I think that the problem is the path of the config file.
If you just from the root path of your application, I mean:

```
- root_dir
    - parser.py
    - config.ini
```

your function will work well, but when you run as an imported lib, you need to pass the whole path to the function.

```
>>import os
>>parser = ConfigParser()
>>parser.read(os.path.abspath('<abs_path_of_config_file>')
```