# How do I make my program move files without the .py file being in the source location

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I wrote this program to move videos from my download folder to different destination folders.

```
import os
import shutil
import sys
folder = []
highlight = ['highlights','goals','skills']
comedy_word = ['comedy', 'acapella','seyilaw','basketmouth','basket mouth','bovi','gordons','buchi','rhythm unplugged','elenu','seyi law','akpororo','emmaohmygod','klint','shakara','funnybone','igodye','i go die','i go dye','igodye','whalemouth','whale mouth','daniel']
series_word = ['lost', 'thrones', 'vampire', 'originals', 'ship', '']
grub_word = ['programming', 'python', 'linux','exploit','hack']


for i in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Afro\\Downloads\\Video'):
    folder.append(i.lower())


def tv_series(series):
    for serie in series:
        if 'ship' in serie:
            shutil.move(serie, 'C:\\Users\\Afro\\Desktop\\Movies\\Series\\The Last Ship\\The Last Ship 3\\' )
            print(serie[:-3] +': Moved!')

        elif 'lost' in serie:
            shutil.move(serie, 'C:\\Users\\Afro\\Desktop\\Movies\\Series\\Lost\\s2\\' )
            print(serie[:-3] +': Moved!')
```

The file's name is arrange.py and the program throws a filenotfound error when arrange.py is not in the "C:\Users\Afro\Downloads\Video" folder. Is it possible to make the program run in any folder?
Thanks
Here's the error it throws.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Afro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shutil.py", line 538, in move
os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'lost - s02e08 (o2tvseries.com).mp4' -> 'C:\\Users\\Afro\\Desktop\\Movies\\Series\\Lost\\s2\\lost - s02e08 (o2tvseries.com).mp4'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Afro\Desktop\Arrange.py", line 77, in <module>
start(folder)
File "C:\Users\Afro\Desktop\Arrange.py", line 65, in start
tv_series(folder)
File "C:\Users\Afro\Desktop\Arrange.py", line 22, in tv_series
shutil.move(serie, 'C:\\Users\\Afro\\Desktop\\Movies\\Series\\Lost\\s2\\' )
File "C:\Users\Afro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shutil.py", line 552, in move
copy_function(src, real_dst)
File "C:\Users\Afro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shutil.py", line 251, in copy2
copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
File "C:\Users\Afro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shutil.py", line 114, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lost - s02e08 (o2tvseries.com).mp4'
```

Comment: Your file not found error is for `arrange.py`? Or is it being generated by `arrange.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `shutil.move` specifying the reference point incorrectly. In your loop that gathers the files, you should use `os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Afro\\Downloads\\Video', i)` and put that in your list instead. Otherwise it's all relative paths, hence the `FileNotFound` error.

You could also change the working directory. This would make the script behave as if it was in a different folder. This can have some unintended consequences, so be careful. [Details here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810743/how-to-set-the-current-working-directory-in-python)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helped, i'm grateful