# How can I set different directory to the current directory in python?

Tags: python, path

I'm trying to open a file that does not exist in my current directory. This file is named `testFile.py` existing in the `data` folder in my current directory. I tried `sys.path.append("./data")` and then wanted to show the file with this command `open("testFile.py")` but it gives this error:

> open("testFile.py") FileNotFoundError:
>
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'testFile.py'

When printing the command `os.getcwd()` gives the previous current directory. So any thoughts on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810743/how-to-set-the-current-working-directory)

Comment: Actually I'm asking about concatenating a directory to my current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
open("data/testFile.py")
```

Or if you need to import...

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.getcwd()+os.sep+"data")
import testFile
```

Not sure if this is what you mean, but if you want to list the files in the subdirectory...

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()+os.sep+"data"
files = os.listdir(path)
print(files)
```

Or you can change the current working directory with...

```
...
os.chdir(path)
```

Comment: For the first case, it gives the same error that no such directory or file exists. For the second one, it doesn't give any error but also doesn't show the file and when I print the directory it gives the previous directory (i.e. not inside the `data` folder.

Comment: I need to import it as a code. I found the file when I did the last part `print(files)` but when I used `open(testFile.py)` it says no file or directory. I think my problem with `open` command. Is there is something alternative?