# Change base directory to upper directory in python

Tags: python, directory

[image]

I am currently working inside the folder `product_graph_analysis`, specifically inside the file `"database_functions.py"` and when I configure my base directory:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

whenever I want to set a path_file:

```
path_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_file.csv')
```

The program will look inside the folder product_graph_analysis.

I would like to set a path_file or base directory in the "mother_folder", the one that contains "csv" and "product_graph_analysis", in this way I could access all folders of my project from within `database_functions.py`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1810743/6464041

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution for this particular case that works fine:

```
import os
file='csv/my_file.csv'
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
HOME_DIR = BASE_DIR.replace('/product_graph_analysis', '')
path_file = os.path.join(HOME_DIR, file)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(BASE_DIR)
'/home/mother_folder/product_graph_analysis'
>>> print(HOME_DIR)
'/home/mother_folder'
```

If yo know a 'better'/'more elegant' option let me know

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to have `BASE_DIR` one directory up, right? Try this one

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..')
```

Assuming this line is located in `database_functions.py`, with this statement you explicitly set BASE dir to the directory one level up (i.e. `<directory of database_functions.py>/..`) than the one in which `database_functions.py` is located specified by `__file__` location.

Please note that this will affects all usages of `BASE_DIR`

Now whenever you want to open any file located in `CSV` subdirectory you should also set it appropriately e.g.

```
path_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'CSV', 'my_file.csv')
```

Comment: I don't think this actually works. The `os.path.dirname` will just remove the `'/..'` from the end (which will in fact be a _deeper_ directory than if you didn't join on the `'..'` in the first place). If you actually want one level _higher_, then maybe you could use `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`.

Comment: @alaniwi: you're right, but I think using `os.path.dirname`should be use inside os.path.join. Correcting my code

Comment: The `dirname(dirname(...))` is what I do in practice with operational code where a package has some scripts inside a `scripts` subdirectory and these scripts need the path of the top-level directory of the package. It has always worked fine, but if you have a neater solution, I'll be interested to see it.

Comment: So `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` will give you directory in which script marked by `__file__` is lokated. What you really need is to _go one directory up_. This can always be achieved by calling `os.path.join(<path>,'..'` as long as you're not in root directory. Although `dirname(dirname(<path_to_file>)` also works as `dirname` simply uses `split` on path and gets first argument

Comment: HOME_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), '..')) its actually taking me 1 directory down: '/home/mother_folder/product_graph_analysis/database_functions.py'

Comment: @TheDan: I actually improve my answer a little. Probably just after you wrote a comment. It should be the other way round i.e. `BASE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..')`