# Set CWD to files location

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get the list of files at the location where my script is.

So let's say I have a directory - `foo/bar`

My script is at `foo/bar/script.py`

I run the script from `foo`

My script is this:

```
import os

print(os.listdir())
```

But when I run it from `foo`, I get the contents of `foo` and not `foo/bar`. I want to get the contents of the script's directory, not the current working directory.

So how do I do this?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use **os.chdir** - try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810760/13228935) answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find script's directory with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934806/how-can-i-find-scripts-directory-with-python). Get the script's directory, then pass it to `listdir(path)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Get the current location from `sys.args` and change your location and then get the list.

```
import os, sys

#print(sys.argv[0]) #check this for file location

os.chdir('\\'.join(sys.argv[0].split('\\')[:-1]))
print(os.listdir())
```

PS: I tested this on Windows, if you are on mac or linux you will have to split with `'/'`

Answer (score -1):

So try going into to foo/bar directory instead of the foo. inside the foo their is only another folder called bar and not a file, so you would only get the folder when u run it. If you are on windows go to Cmd type "cd foo/bar".

I hope this helped!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Formatting your answers will look good. format it to make it more helpful for others