# Delete a directory using Python?

Tags: python

I am getting the output of a directory using subprocess like this :-

```
directory_content = subprocess.getoutput("ssh -i /key.pem ubuntu@IP ls -l --time-style=long-iso /opt/orientdb/databases" | awk -F' ' '{print $6 $8}'")
```

And i am converting the output to a list of tuples such that i get the directory and the date on which the directory was created.

```
[('2019-04-25', 'database1'), ('2019-04-26', 'database2') .......]
```

And i am looping over list and getting the respective directory

```
for date,db in directory_content:
    if (date == '2019-04-25'):
        os.remove(db)
```

but i am getting the error message :-

```
 os.remove(db)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I can use some help on how i can delete the directory. Thank you.

Comment: The error means what it says. Double check your file name spellings and paths

Comment: Is the python file executed in the same directory as database1, database2, etc..... And is there any file extensions missing?

Comment: You should either (1) [change the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810760/) to where the files are located or (2) [use absolute paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51523/).

Comment: @12944qwerty i will have to disagree with you. The directory definitely exists.

Comment: @Somethingwhatever are you sure your path is correct? Check the links that Enzo sent

Comment: maybe try setting variable `db = /whole/path/` and then `os.remove(db)`

Comment: @RMRiver  I am using subprocess to ssh into another VM and then get the directory info.

Comment: @Somethingwhatever Just to confirm, you are running the python script in the VM and not locally?

Comment: @RMRiver i am running it locally.

Comment: @Somethingwhatever If the python file is running locally, it won't be able to delete "database1" that is within a VM.... You need to run the scipt within the VM, or ssh with python into the vpn.

Answer (score 1):

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

That doesn't say you can't delete the file.  That says there is no file.  The computer is surely telling you truth about that.

I see two problems.

1. The directory list is fetched from **ubuntu@IP**, but afaict `os.remove` is executed locally.  That could be a ... problem.
2. The directory names are relative to `/opt/orientdb/databases`, but there's no evidence that's the current working directory when the process executes.

For any *file not found* error in Python that "can't be", a good strategy is to wrap the offending code in a try/catch block and, when the exception is caught, print both the argument name and the current working directory.  Nearly always, when you string those two pieces of information together, you'll agree with the computer with a resounding, "duh!".